# MS Release Management- Release template build definition is empty

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, ms-release-management

First time i am trying to access the build definition from release template and the dropdowns are empty.
[image]
Please note, my RM client is connected to a TFS and it's listed under Administration > Manage TFS.

Did I miss any permission setting?

Comment: Are you a Release Manager? This error can happen when the permissions are incorrectly configured

Comment: What version of RM do you have?

Comment: try http V https, ensure the RM account exists in TFS

Comment: I am a release manager and I have RM for TFS 2013. @JustTFS I have connected TFS using a TFS account and that account is created in RM as well. Thank you all for the comments...!!

Comment: Please go to Administration->Settings, let us know the System Version displayed there.

Comment: System version: 12.0.30501.0

Comment: My TFS build is failing when, ReleaseBuild=True. I suspect both issues are dependent.

Comment: TFS build error is:

 Exception Message: The directory name is invalid (type Win32Exception)
Exception Stack Trace: 
Server stack trace: 
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.InvokeProcess.ProcessWrapper.Start()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.InvokeProcess.InvokeProcessInternal.RunCommand(AsyncState state)

Comment: This is a road blocking issue for me, please help me.. Thank you very much for the comments..!!

Comment: So you can now see the builds? And the build is calling out to RM and the deployment is failing. Or you still can't map the builds in RM?

Comment: I still can't map the builds in RM... :(

Comment: This is commonly either a http/https issue or permissions. Does the account that you use to connect RM to TFS exist in the "Service Accounts" group on TFS?

Comment: Yes i have verified the account. Do we need to install RM client/Server in the same TFS build server to achieve this..? Thank  you for the comment.

Comment: I'm on version 12.0.30723.0 Update 3, and experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Some one please help me... :(

Comment: I am not able to resolve this issue. I have installed RM server and client in the build server, now i am able to access the build definition. Previously there were no domain trust between build server and RM installed server, but i was able to connect TFS. Issue is related to domain trust i believe...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed RM server and client in the build server, now I am able to access the build definition. Previously there were no domain trust between build server and RM installed server, but I was able to connect TFS. Issue was related to domain trust I believe...!